# How can I stop Google analytics tracking session when my app enters into background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, google-analytics

Using Google analytics v3 for my iOS app.

I tried to manually stop the current session when my app enters background and start a new session when my App enters foreground.

But it fails.

Here is my code :

In Appdelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary       *)launchOptions

{
    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
    [[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelError];
    [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-54600000-1"];

    NSLog(@"Analytics Started");
}
```

and in

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  //  Here
  //  I WANT TO CLOSE THE CURRENT SESSION  
}
```

and in

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   //   HERE
   //   I WANT TO START A NEW SESSION
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable an app-level opt out flag that will disable Google Analytics across the entire app. Once set, the flag will persist for the life of the app or until it is reset.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
 //  Here
 // THE CURRENT SESSION  

  [[GAI sharedInstance].setOptOut = YES];
  }


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
//   HERE
//    START A NEW SESSION

// Get a new tracker.
id newTracker = [[GAI sharedInstance]trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-NEW-TRACKING-ID");

// Set the new tracker as the default tracker, globally.
[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker = newTracker;
}
```

need ref on more knowledge use this [google analytics link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/advanced)

additional information have a nice [tutorial](http://www.tatvic.com/blog/iphone-application-tracking-google-analytics/)

Comment: Using the same tracking id , i need to manage sessions which the default session is 30mins.

Comment: i need to stop the current session when my user enters background

Comment: it automatically refresh in every 30 minutes, if u goes on background it automatically stop , when u comes back on screen it called the automatic tracking (self.screenname)and event tracking (hit action), no need of this  [[GAI sharedInstance].setOptOut = YES]; and this id newTracker = [[GAI sharedInstance]trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-NEW-TRACKING-ID");

// Set the new tracker as the default tracker, globally.
[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker = newTracker;

Comment: sure : karthik.saral@gmail.com (Gmail,Skype,FB,stackoverflow), now i m leaving from office, if anything ask on tomorrow, have a nice day my brother

Comment: yeah i know it will refresh in 30mins automatically , but i want to know how long my user is active in my app...
so oly i raised this question...

Comment: oh ,nice question bro, i am also used GA in last 3 projects but i am did this, k tomorrow mrng i answer this question..